# Ruby on Rails: How do you get the previous URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to get the previous URL in Rails? Not the URL that you got a request from, but the one before that?

Because I'm getting an AJAX request, and I need the URL for the page they are currently on (or the URL before the AJAX).

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Try to use `HTTP_REFERER`.

In Rails: `request.referrer` or `request.headers["HTTP_REFERER"]`

Answer (score 20):

Use

```
<%= url_for(:back) %>
# if request.env["HTTP_REFERER"] is set to "http://www.example.com"
# => http://www.example.com
```

[here is more details.](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.14/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-url_for)

Answer (score 7):

In a web application there is no such thing as a previous url. The http protocol is stateless, so each request is independent of each other.

You could have the Javascript code, that sends a request back, send the current url with the request.

Comment: that's exactly the correct answer and we all should read Roy Fielding's paper again!

Answer (score 4):

Just came across this question and it related to something simple I was doing presently.

A simple solution I have employed before when using ajax wizard style apps is to store two session variables which contain the previous and current request (with  all params).
I just add these two lines to my application controller

```
session[:previous_request_url] = session[:current_request_url]
session[:current_request_url] = request.url
```

Answer (score 2):

http://railscasts.com/episodes/246-ajax-history-state -> great for ajax

http://ethilien.net/archives/better-redirects-in-rails/ -> You could put in session as many previous url as you want.