# how do you determine if request.referrer matches a Rails restful path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

As we know from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652084/ruby-on-rails-how-do-you-get-the-previous-url), in Rails, you can get the previous url by calling

```
request.referrer
```

But how do you check if the previous url matches one of the restful paths in
your Rails application?

By restful paths, I mean paths provided by Rails, such as,

```
books_path
book_path(book)
edit_book_path(book)
```

Of course I can do a regular expression string match on request.referrer, but I think it's a bit ugly.

One particular case, in my application, is that request.referrer can be
"localhost:3000/books?page=4"

and I want to it to match

```
books_path
```

which returns "/books"

In this case, how can I check if there's a match without doing regular expression string
match? (if this is at all possible)

Thanks

P.S. I have tried regular expression string match, and it works.  I just thought there might be a better way in Rails.

Comment: Why can't you just check the domain part of the referrer to see if it's coming from an internal/external url? If internal, then it will be a route defined in your app, if not, it won't.

Comment: @varatis, i don't think you understood my question.  checking the domain of the url is very simple.  i want to know if this previous url matches the "index" path of books (in my example). how do I do that without doing regex comparison?

Comment: If you're just looking at one path, it seems like using a regex or string comparison would be simplest.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could extract the path portion of the `request.referer` using the following:

```
URI(request.referer).path
```

You can then use `Rails.application.routes.recognize_path` to check if path maps to a controller and action, e.g.:

```
my_path = URI(request.referer).path 
# => /books

Rails.application.routes.recognize_path(my_path)
# => {:action=>"show", :controller=>"books", :page=>"4"}
```

Comment: Warning: the `recognize_path` method is deprecated.

Comment: OK. Any suggestions for a substitute?

Comment: Also be careful that it does not run constraints and thus may return false positives.

Answer (score 3):

Though not certain of what you want to do with that, pretty sure rails support better ways of controlling redirects. Nevertheless, I guess this is what you are looking for:

`request.referer == books_url(page: params[:page])`

**UPDATED:**

This way, even if there's no params[:page]. This would still work properly.

Comment: thanks for the answer.  however, page 4 is only an example, it could be page 7, or may not contain page  param at all.  so clearly hard-coding page 4 here is not what i want.

Comment: I figured that, but it was just an example as well.

you could use `request.referer == books_url(page: params[:page])`, this way, even if there's no params[:page] it would work as intended. give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Since `recognize_path` was deprecated, this is another way of doing it:

Name your route in your routes config using the `as` keyword:

```
get 'foo/bar' => 'foo#bar', as: :foo_bar
```

Then you can do the check like this:

```
if URI(request.referer).path == foo_bar_path
  do_something()
end
```