# accessing previous URL in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using devise for authentication. My scenario is as below.

User goes to `http://localhost/deep1/deep2` but as a user is not authenticated user is redirected to the login page `http://localhost/login`.

Now on a login page I have before filter in which I want to access the page from which unauthenticated call was triggered.

TO access the previous URL, I have tried using `request.env["HTTP_REFERER"]`
and also `request.referrer`

Is there anything I am missing? Or there is some other way to handle this scenario?

Answer is in : [Devise and stored_location_for: how do you store the return location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028025/devise-and-stored-location-for-how-do-you-store-the-return-location)

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652084/ruby-on-rails-how-do-you-get-the-previous-url

Comment: Thanks for a link. I have already gone through it. It didn't help.

Comment: If you use Devise for authentication, have a look at `store_location`. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028025/devise-and-stored-location-for-how-do-you-store-the-return-location

Comment: The general idea is that, store the desired location, say in session, before you redirect to the login page and use it after the user has successfully logged in.

Comment: if you are using devise...try this .. https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-back-to-current-page-after-sign-in,-sign-out,-sign-up,-update